# Appcelerator Titanium TableView takes long time to load

Tags: data-binding, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, data-collection

I have a controller in which I have a table view like this:

```
<TableView id="reservedScroll"  dataCollection="queue"  dataTransform="transformFunction"  dataFilter="reservedByDate"  layout="vertical" >
    (some rows) 
</TableView>
```

I create 6 object of this controllers and push them into a scrollable view

```
for (var i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {
    $.scrollableView.addView(Alloy.createController('dateQueues', {index : i}).getView());
}
```

In this case I filter the collection 6 times (filtering each table by different date)

The problem is it's taking really long time to load (about 15-20 seconds) , so it made me wonder if my solution is a good titanium programming practice.

Any thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Controller is too heavy-weight to be created in a loop.

Try splitting your controller into several parts (templates) and using them instead. More info in [this tutorial](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Views_without_Controllers)